C: Reading terminal key combinations (Ctrl+shift+)
I'm trying to build a simple terminal program with ncurses, but I'm having a hardtime trying to read key combinations like (Ctrl+shift+) or (Ctrl+)
I tried other libraries like libtickit which can read these combinations in desktop terminals but doesn't work well in TTY-only (I'm using Linux).
I saw nano uses ncurses and they support this combinations (like Ctrl+shift+arrows) but the code is very complex.
Does anybody knows a way or any other library (even in other language) that can detect this key combinations for most of modern unix terminals?
Thanks.

You cannot read Ctrl+shift+arrows with ncurses or with anything else because the terminal driver doesn't produce such combinations. You can press Ctrl+shift+left, but the result will be exactly the same as with left alone.

The terminal absolutely does produce such combinations. They even have their own names in terminfo. (Not all terminals do, naturally, but modern emulators all tend to follow the set that do.)

Sorry my bad, the driver actually produces all the combimations.

First, there is no such thing as a “simple” terminal program. Sorry.
Some modifier+key combinations can be detected just fine, but not all, and not for all keys for a given modifier set.
You absolutely CAN decode Ctrl+Shift+Left Arrow!
And you can do it on both *nixen and on Windows! But we will focus on *nixen here (which includes WSL) as-per your question’s tags.
Pressing just, for example, Ctrl+A gets you a ^A, which has the key code value of 1. Likewise, Ctrl+B gets you the key value of 2. (In C you would write those as '\1' and '\2'.)
These are your standard “control codes”. Not every key on your keyboard produces a control code, and some do without the need for the Ctrl key, such as Return and Backspace.
And backspace is a rat’s nest on *nixen anyway — you need extra logic to return a correctvalue to your program, depending on whom you ask. But that is an issue for a different day.
Most anything with an Alt key is just the keycode prefixed with the Esc key code (27). Again, not every key can be successfully used in combination with Alt.
Likewise, Shift’s effect depends on the key. Outside of specials (like the arrow keys) it only works reliably for alphanumeric keys (toggling their state — Caps Lock must be tracked as well! Like, WT--?!)

Fortunately, pressing Ctrl+Shift+Left Arrow produces a short, recognizable escape sequence (specifically: Esc;6D). That 6 in there is the key to recognizing which modifier keys are pressed: subtract 1 and the bits set are your modifier key code:



bit
2
1
0




modifier
Ctrl
Alt
Shift



So 6-1 = 5, meaning bits 0 and 2 are set, which are Shift and Ctrl.
You won’t get it like that when using Curses, though. If you are using Curses you must ask for the “key name” using the keyname() function (man 3NCURSES util). For Ctrl+Shift+Left Arrow, the key name is... “kLFT6”! Very convenient!
What this suggests is that you should be using a lookup table to decide whether a specific (modifiers + arrow key) combination has been input, rather than try to select on them separately.
Don’t worry too much about trying to be extra efficient with strings and stuff. Even if using a string lookup, it’ll have completed before your user’s finger has left contact with the key.

What makes all this extra complicated is the historical use of the “meta” key, which is inexplicably mapped to the Esc key, making timing an issue. In other words, special care must be made to read key response sequences. Make sure to add initialization code to your program to set the esc_delay() to something reasonably small:
int DEFAULT_ESC_DELAY = 100; // 50..150 ms are reasonable values,
// assuming you are using a local terminal. If user is using dialup/
// network terminal, he/she should have ESCDELAY set in the environment
// anyway!

int get_esc_delay_value(void)
{
  const char * s = getenv( "ESCDELAY" );
  if (!s) return DEFAULT_ESC_DELAY;

  errno = 0;
  char * end;
  long n = strtol( s, &end, 0 );
  if ((s == end) or (errno) or (*end)) return DEFAULT_ESC_DELAY;

  if (n <    0) return 0;
  if (n > 5000) return 5000; // 5 sec is insanely large, but...

  return n;
}

...

esc_delay( get_esc_delay_value() );


Finally, there are likely limits imposed by the terminal itself, the OS, and even the terminal emulator options!
For example, chances are that Ctrl+Shift+Up Arrow has been snagged by your terminal emulator, meaning your program will never see it. And getting the user to figure out how to remove a convenient shortcut from his or her TE is something you can put in the “too hard to compute” bucket.
AAAaaaaaaaaaaaarrrrgggghhhhh!
